# how updating contextMenuStrip1?

Tags: c#

I'm new with C#

I have create a contextMenuStrip1 with:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.contextMenuStrip1.Items[1].Select();
    Update();
}
```

I have a TOP "MenuItem" to ensure to put the windows on TOP or not ... it's work fine, but the item TOP still check in any case

```
private void topToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Update();
    if (topToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true)

    if (this.TopMost == false)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.TopMost = false;
        }
}
```

how can i clear the menu if i check or not the TOP item?

regards

Comment: You can add your event handler for your check box :)

Comment: thx you Bob, how can i manage that ? it's related to EventArgs ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check this out : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Don't hesitate to reply ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally used a button to TOP my Form, and it's work fine.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.TopMost = false;
    }
}
```

thx you